# Weak derivative of projection onto probabilist's simplex

Tags: pr.probability, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-optimization, closed-form-expressions

Let $\Delta_n:=\{x\in [0,1]^n:\boldsymbol{1}^{\top}x=1\}$ denote the probabilist's $n$-simplex and let $P:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\Delta_n$ denote the (Euclidean) metric projection onto this simplex defined for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$
P(x):=\operatorname{argmin}_{\tilde{x}\in \Delta_n}\,\|x-\tilde{x}\|^2.
$$

This function is $1$-Lipschitz and therefore by Rademacher's theorem it is a.e. differentiable.  Is it's weak derivative known explicitly in closed-form?

*I have been looking in the proximity operator literature but nothing yet...*

[Related Discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402504/orthogonal-projection-onto-the-unit-simplex)

Comment: See Theorem 5.2 in   the  book "*Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*" by Haim Brezis.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something, but why does this result give the closed-form expression?

Comment: There is (to my knowledge) no closed-form solution, but there are efficient algorithms; see https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.6081 and the references therein.

Comment: Ah, I see that this reference (and the Condat paper, which is the second key reference) is already given in the answers to the linked math.stackexchange.com question. As far as I know, there's nothing to add to that.

Comment: In this case $P$ is piecewise affine so the differential is easy to compute.   If $P(x)$ belongs to the relative interior of a $k$-dimensional face, say $x_{k+2}=\cdots =x_n=0$ and $x_1,\dotsc, x_k>0$, then  the  differential of $P(x)$ at $x$ is the orthogonal projection onto the $k$-plane   given by the equations $$x_1+\cdots+x_{k+1}=x_{k+1}=\cdots =x_n=0.$$